# Killing a thread with a complex subroutine. Java

Tags: java, multithreading, abort

As many others I have a problem killing my thread without using stop().
I have tried to use volatile on a variable with a while loop in my threads run() routine.

The problem is as far as I can see, that the while loop only checks the variable before every turn. The complex routine Im running takes a long time, and because of that the thread is not terminated immediately.

The thread I want to terminate is a routine that connects to another server and it uses a looooong time. And I want to have an abort button for this. (Terminating the thread). I'll try to explane with some code.

```
class MyConnectClass{
    Thread conThread;
    volitile boolean threadTerminator = false;

        ..some code with connect and abort button..


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String btnName = e.getActionCommand();

        if(btnName.equalsIgnoreCase("terminate")){

            threadTerminator = true;
            conThread.interrupt();
            System.out.println("#INFO# USER ABORTED CURRENT OPERATION!");

        }else if(btnName.equalsIgnoreCase("connectToServer")){

            conThread = new Thread() { 
                public void run() {
                    while(threadTerminator == false){

                        doComplexConnect(); //Uses a loooong time
                    }
                }
            }
            conThread.start();  
        }   
    }
}
```

How can I kill my "connection" thread instantly?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you interrupt the thread using the normal interrupt facilities?

Comment: Im trying to use conThread.interrupt();  in a hope that the thread would abort possible subthreads. My connect method uses ssh to another location, and it waits for the remote location to answare. Was it "conThread.interrupt();" you ment with normal interrupt facilities?

Comment: Can you clarify your outer problem, because most likely the solution has nothing to do with the thread. Why do you need to abort the operation so quickly?

Comment: My conThread is waiting for a remote ssh shell to answare. And this is what takes such a long time. I want to abort this thread (and the waiting) with my "abort" button. My main thread has disabled other connection_buttons while waiting for this one to finish. And I want to abort so I can enable the buttons for other operations.

Comment: So shutdown the TCP connection and the wait will stop. (Stop the actual thing you want stopped, not the thread.)

Comment: and Im not able to run this method in the main thread, because the main thread is doing other operations, like updating a console window with connection infomation from my ConThread.

Comment: Ok, I will see if I can find a way to terminate the TCP connection. If I can manage to access my conThread from my main thread. I'll give it a try. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Java abandoned the stop() approach in Threads a while back because killing a Thread ungracefully caused huge problems in the JVM. From the Javadoc for stop():

> Stopping a thread with Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked ThreadDeath exception propagating up the stack). If any of the objects previously protected by these monitors were in an inconsistent state, the damaged objects become visible to other threads, potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior. Many uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The target thread should check this variable regularly, and return from its run method in an orderly fashion if the variable indicates that it is to stop running. If the target thread waits for long periods (on a condition variable, for example), the interrupt method should be used to interrupt the wait.

In most cases, it is up to you to check the threadTerminator var whenever it is safe for you to terminate, and handle the thread exit gracefully. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: Hi, thanks.
The problem is that I am not able to check the threadTerminator because my conThread is waiting for a remote ssh shell to answare. And this is what takes so long time. I want to abort this thread (and the waiting) with my "abort" button.?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing long I/O, you may be in trouble.  Some I/O operations throw an InterruptedException, in which case, you can *interrupt* the thread, and, *if* you were in that I/O, that exception will be thrown more or less instantly, and you can abort and cleanup the thread.  For this reason, interrupting a thread is preferable to using a special custom threadTerminator variable - it's much more standard.  In you main code outside of the I/O, check for interrupted() or isInterrupted() periodically (instead of threadTerminator == false).

If you are doing I/O that doesn't throw InterruptedException, sometimes you can close the Socket or similar, and catch the IOException.  And sometimes you are stuck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. Im still working on this. I will try to chech interrupted().

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you interrupt the thread and just move on, letting it hang until it finishes? The user could initiate a different action (thread) while the old thread finishes gracefully (which, from what I see you are pretty much doing already btw)

The downside of this that you have trouble when the user starts clicking "connectToServer" a lot (many threads), or when the threads fail to terminate (hanged threads). But maybe it's sufficient for your purpose?

Edit:
It would be simple to implement a mechanism that prevents spawning a new conthread unless "it's good to go" (e.g., use a semaphore).

The tricky part will be deciding whether it's good to open a new connection. You could ask the original thread (I.e. have a isalive() method), or the party you are trying to connect to. Or you could go for a timeout solution. For example, you could let conthread update a timestamp and decide it's dead if the timestamp isn't updated for 1 min etc. The most generally applicable solution would probably be the timeout solution.

Comment: Hi, this is a good suggestion. The only problem is that the conThread is sending updates to a console that my main thread is updating(gui). So if I run multible conThreads the console window will be a big mess. Like: connecting, connecting, sending command, disconnecting, sending command, etc..  Any suggestion? :)

Comment: That's probably simple: Either make sure that before any such operation, the thread checks if it should live or die (check the interrupted status in the update-sending methods). Or ignore these updated unless they come from the only thread which should still be alive (this is IMHO quite messy).